# Spring MVC Upload file in form no file validation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload

I've a requirement in Spring MVC for file upload. I created the file in form and able to populate the value in same properly. However, I've to check if file is provided by user or not(empty file will also be considered as file provided). I need to throw an error in case file provided is empty.

My validation method for form is mentioned below:

```
@Override
public void validate(Object uploadedFile, Errors errors) {

    UploadedFile file = (UploadedFile) uploadedFile;

    if (file.getFile().getSize() == 0) {
        errors.rejectValue("file", "uploadForm.emptyFile",
                "File is empty");
    }

}
```

Checking size returns 0 for both cases(file not selected and file is empty). Please suggest if there is way to validate if file is empty. I found an alternate way to do the same(to check if file.getFile().getOriginalFileName() is empty), however it doesn't seem to be the appropriate way. Please suggest if there is other possible good solution.

Comment: If you're using HTML5, I suggest moving these valuations on client side also.

Comment: Thanks S R chaitanya for your comment, however, we need to throw an error if file provided is empty and allowed to proceed if no file is selected, I'll update the question as well to clarify the same.

Comment: Also, I've checked file.getFile().isEmpty() which is returning true for both the cases

Comment: You can try using Spring's MultiPartFile (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html).  Use getContentType method in this class to find whether the file is uploaded or not and use isEmpty/getSize to find out if the file size is zero or not. By using both together one can easily differentiate between file uploaded or not vs zero byte sized file upload.